# Number of minima vs. maxima of a periodic function

Tags: maxima-minima, periodic-functions

Consider a continuous periodic function $f$ of $n > 1$ real variables (by this I mean there exists a full rank lattice of symmetries). Does $f$ have as many local maxima as local minima inside one fundamental cell?

Answer (score 0):

A lattice of square-based pyramids provides a simple counter-example: there is one local maximum per cell, but the whole boundary of each cell is a local minimum.

If you would prefer a differentiable counter-example, take [$f(x,y)=\sin^2 x\sin^2 y$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+sin%5E2+x+sin%5E2+y).

Comment: I see, thanks. What if we demand that $f$ has only isolated maxima and minima? The connected set of minima in your example could "morally" be viewed as a single minimum.

Comment: If that's your moral position, then there is only a single minimum over the entire plane! So we get more maxima than minima. But in any case we can perturb the boundaries of the cell (where $f$ iz zero) by a sine wave with a small period (e.g. $\pi/10$); if the magnitude of this perturbation is small enough, we end up with many isolated minima per cell, without creating any local maxima.

Comment: Sorry, could you write out that function explicitly, please? I'd like to understand why the answer is negative in $n > 1$ but (I think) clearly positive for $n=1$.